# Multiple workbook_change events VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some trouble in combining 2 workbook change event so I can use them both in the same sheet ( not so experienced in VBA yet)

the situation is as followed:
I use a barcode scanner in this process and during the process I have no access to a mouse or a keyboard.

In the workbook is only 1 cell unlocked, the first workbook_change event is only activated when the correct "START" code gets scanned into this cell.

code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Intersect(Target, [B4]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  If [B4] = "START" Then

 Startcode

    End If

  End Sub
```

This part works fine and unlocks a new range where I can scan codes, these codes are combined in a string for later use in the process, but if somewhere in that range a specific "SCAN COMPLETE" code is scanned it should run another macro.

This is what I came up with:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

     For Each cell In Target

       If Intersect(cell, Range("A1:A15")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

     If [A1] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
        test
      ElseIf [A2] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
         test
      ElseIf [A3] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
         test
      ElseIf [A4] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
         test
      ElseIf [A5] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A6] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A7] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A8] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A9] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A10] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A11] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A12] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A13] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
          test
      ElseIf [A14] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
         test
      ElseIf [A15] = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then
         test

      End If

       Next cell

      End Sub
```

Probably not the best code but it works (only need to make the range bigger)
now I want to have both codes running on the same worksheet but till this point I have not been able to get it to work. Can somebody maybe help me a little bit

Comment: Don't you just need to put the second bit of code into where it says Startcode in the first? Also just use `if target = "SCAN COMPLETE"` to replace all those Ifs.

Comment: Thanks for the if target = "SCAN COMPLETE" i tried and it worked.  in the first part where it says "start code" it runs a macro called start code wich unlocks the range A1:A15so that the next codes im scanning wil go to that range

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'might need to disable events somewhere depending on what other subs do

Dim cell As Range

If Target.Address = "$B$4" Then
    If Target.Value = "START" Then Startcode
End If

If Range("B4").Value = "START" Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A15")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A15"))
            If cell.Value = "SCAN COMPLETE" Then test
        Next cell
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tested it and it does exactly what it should